# Nginx only passes one cookie to custom directive

Tags: cookies, nginx

I'm using the following code to output the number of cookies, their headers and values.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "'";
ngx_array_t cookies = ctx->initiatingRequest->headers_in.cookies;
ngx_table_elt_t** cookieTable = reinterpret_cast<ngx_table_elt_t**>(cookies.elts);
for (unsigned int i=0; i < cookies.nelts; i++) {
    ss << std::string(reinterpret_cast<char *>(cookieTable[i]->key.data),cookieTable[i]->key.len) << "-" << std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cookieTable[i]->value.data),cookieTable[i]->value.len) << "+";
}
ss << cookies.nelts << "'";
```

I have tried a number of different things but "headers_in.cookies" appears to only ever contain 1 cookie, no matter how many are set. (I also tried this with the headers in general and obtained the same result.) Is there something special in nginx or my code that I might need to enable or disable? I can't find anything in the custom module itself that is explicitly eliminating duplicates.

**Edit:** nginx debug logs show Cookie being sent as a semi-colon separated list instead of multiple headers. Could that be it, and if so, how do I change it?

I also notice that the debug log doesn't contain the "parse header:" debug log line found in the ngx_http_parse_multi_header_lines function.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the way the objects in nginx are setup, there was in fact only a single cookie header that contained all the objects. This was being obfuscated by the fact that the additional semicolons from having multiple cookies in one line was causing a break in the Set-Cookie header (not seen above) I was using as output.